# Trying the download an excel file form the sharepoint online

Tags: excel, powershell, sharepoint

I am trying to download an excel file from sharepoint location using powershell script, but I get the error messages:

Add-Type : Cannot bind parameter 'Path' to the target. Exception setting "Path": "Cannot find path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll' because it does not exist."

Add-Type : Cannot bind parameter 'Path' to the target. Exception setting "Path": "Cannot find path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll' because it does not exist."

My PowerShell script is given below:

```
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
 
#Function to copy a given sourcefile to downloadpath
Function Download-FileFromLibrary()
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $SiteURL,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $SourceFileURL,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $TargetFilePath
    )
 
    Try {
        #Setup Credentials to connect
        $Cred= Get-Credential
        $Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.Username, $Cred.Password)
 
        #Setup the context
        $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
        $Ctx.Credentials = $Credentials
     
        #sharepoint online powershell download file from library
        $FileInfo = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File]::OpenBinaryDirect($Ctx,$SourceFileURL)
        $WriteStream = [System.IO.File]::Open($TargetFilePath,[System.IO.FileMode]::Create)
        $FileInfo.Stream.CopyTo($WriteStream)
        $WriteStream.Close()
 
        Write-host -f Green "File '$SourceFileURL' Downloaded to '$TargetFilePath' Successfully!" $_.Exception.Message
  }
    Catch {
        write-host -f Red "Error Downloading File!" $_.Exception.Message
    }
}
 
#Set parameter values
$SiteURL="https://domain.sharepoint.com/Shared%20Documents/"
$SourceFileURL="/Shared%20Documents/testFileRealData02.xlsx"  #Server Relative URL
$TargetFilePath="C:\temp\file"
 
#Call the function to download file
Download-FileFromLibrary -SiteURL $SiteURL -SourceFileURL $SourceFileURL -TargetFilePath $TargetFilePath
```

Answer (score 0):

The 1st few lines of the script is trying to import libraries to make their functions / classes available for the rest of the script.

You need to download and install 'SharePoint Online Client Components SDK' as these are the libraries you are missing.

The can be found using the following link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the PnP.Powershell module instead?
I think it's way easier to handle.

You can install it by using:

```
Install-Module -Name PnP.PowerShell -RequiredVersion 1.12.0
```

(There is a newer version of the module available but you need Powershell 7.2 to use it:
https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PnP.PowerShell/1.12.0)

This example connects to the desired SPO site.
My .xlsx file is stored in the Documents folder of a Teams site.

```
Import-Module PnP.Powershell

#Make connect
$SpoUrl = "https://TENANT.sharepoint.com/sites/SITENAME"
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SpoUrl -UseWebLogin
#You can also use your stored credentials instead
$Connection = (Get-PnPConnection)

#Find your file
$DocumentsFolder = Get-PnPList | where {$_.Title -like 'Documents'}
$Items = Get-PnPListItem -List $DocumentsFolder.Id | select -ExpandProperty "FieldValues"
$ItemToDownload = $Items | where {$_.FileRef -like 'FILENAME.xlsx'}

#Download file
$NewTargetPath = $env:TEMP
Get-PnPFile -Url $ItemToDownload.FileRef -AsFile -Path $NewTargetPath -Filename $ItemToDownload.FileLeafRef -Force
```

I hope this helps.